# How to substract amount input from current balance to get available balance in python Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have available balance field and current balance field in my user profile model in Django. I want to substract amount input from current balance to get available balance show in my web page of the user profile

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `save()` function in your `UserProfile` model

example:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.available_balance = (self.current_balance - self.amount_input)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can add more information like the model code to get the concise answer. Hope that one helped let me know.